# Is it possible to make a 1 pixel diagonal line unbroken in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

Basically I need to draw a 1 pixel line but I want it so that the line is unbroken. Currently what happens is if I draw diagonally the pixels will touch corner to corner and I want it so they will only be side to side. Basically I want it so that when I draw a 1 pixel line diagonally the fuzzy select will be able to get the whole line.

---

What it is doing
x--
-x-
--x

---

What I want it to do

x--
xxx
--x

---

Is there a setting or script somewhere I can set so that I can get what I want?

Comment: What about 2 pixel lines? Does that help or complicate afterward?

Answer (score 2):

Simply duplicate your 1 pixel line and shift it across by 1 pixel:

[image]